# How to Start GrizzlyWebContainer at start of test class and shutdown after test class execution

Tags: jersey

I am using JerseyTest to test RESTful webservices. one thing i observed is grizzly is start/stop for every method which takes long time to run my test. is there way to start/stop the grizzly once for entire test class.

```
public class JerseyTestBase extends JerseyTest {

@Override
protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory()
        throws TestContainerException {
    return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
}

public JerseyTestBase() {

    super(new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("xxx.xxx.controller") 
    .contextPath("test") 
    .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:spring/application-context.xml")             
    .contextListenerClass(ContextLoaderListener.class)
    .requestListenerClass(RequestContextListener.class)
    .servletPath("/*")
    .servletClass(SpringServlet.class)
    .initParam("JSONConfiguration.Builder.rootUnwrapping", "true")
    .initParam("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "false")
    .initParam("com.sun.jersey.config.property.MediaTypeMappings", "json :  pplication/json")
    .initParam("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters", "com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter")
    .initParam("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters", "com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter")
    .build());
}
```

}

actual test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:spring/application-context.xml"/*,     "classpath:applicationContext-unittest.xml"*/})
public class PurchaseManagerClientControllerTestCase extends JerseyTestBase {}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's currently possible directly using `JerseyTest`, but you could create your own customized parent test class based on `JerseyTest` and use the **`@BeforeClass`** and **`@AfterClass`** annotations (from `org.junit` package) instead of `@Before` and `@After`.

Methods annotated by those must be `static`, so you'll need to rewrite the original class a bit more, but if you do not need the versatility of `JerseyTest` in terms of using multiple `TestContainer` implementations, you can create significantly simpler version of your own test base class. 
Basically just use some code from the `JerseyTest` constructor to initialize Jersey application and some code from `GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.GrizzlyTestContainer` class to start/stop the server, etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but here's the answer (I had exactly the same need)

This solution came up after this discussion whith Jersey maintainers: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/4606

```java
package org.opensilex.integration.test;

import java.net.URI;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.DeploymentContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import static org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.closeIfNotNull;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.TestProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerException;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerFactory;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public abstract class SingleServerStartStopForTestClass extends JerseyTest {

    private static TestContainerFactory testContainerFactory;
    private static TestContainer globalTestContainer = null;
    private static Client globalClient = null;

    @AfterClass
    public static void stopGlobalContainer() throws Exception {
        try {
            if (globalTestContainer != null) {
                globalTestContainer.stop();
            }
        } finally {
            closeIfNotNull(globalClient);
        }
        globalTestContainer = null;
        globalClient = null;
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        if (globalClient == null) {
            globalClient = this.getClient();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Client getClient() {
        if (globalClient == null) {
            return super.getClient();
        } else {
            return globalClient;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() throws TestContainerException {
        if (testContainerFactory == null) {
            testContainerFactory = new CustomTestContainerFactory();
        }
        return testContainerFactory;
    }

    private class CustomTestContainerFactory extends GrizzlyTestContainerFactory {

        @Override
        public TestContainer create(URI baseUri, DeploymentContext context) {
            if (globalTestContainer == null) {
                globalTestContainer = super.create(baseUri, context);
            }
            return globalTestContainer;
        }

    }

    @After
    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // Overriden to avoid
    }

    @Override
    protected ResourceConfig configure() {

        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);

        ResourceConfig resourceConfig;
        try {

            // initialize application
            resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();

            // create a mock for HttpServletRequest which is not available with grizzly
            final HttpServletRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
            resourceConfig.register(new AbstractBinder() {
                @Override
                protected void configure() {
                    bind(request).to(HttpServletRequest.class);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return resourceConfig;
    }
}
```